# Stripping out all Timber logs from my apk

Tags: android, android-studio, proguard, timber-android

I use the below code in my proguard rules to strip out any log.d i may have left before i compile the release apk.

```
> -assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
>     public static *** d(...);
>     public static *** v(...); }
```

Is there a way to do it for all timber logs?

```
Timber.w("This shouldn't show in release apk when decompiled");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would the same approach - but using a `Timber` class instead of `Log` - not work? E.g.:

```
-assumenosideeffects class timber.log.Timber* {
    public static *** v(...);
    public static *** d(...);
    public static *** i(...);
}
```

Alternatively, you could follow the [sample project](https://github.com/JakeWharton/timber/blob/master/timber-sample/src/main/java/com/example/timber/ExampleApp.java) and do something like:

```
public class App extends Application {
  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
      Timber.plant(new DebugTree());
    } else {
      Timber.plant(new ProductionTree());
    }
  }

  private static class ProductionTree extends Timber.Tree {
    @Override
    protected void log(int priority, String tag, String message, Throwable t) {
      // Do whatever (or nothing) here.
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: the proguard code worked.
the second approach which was recommended doesn't actually strip the code, just changes its implementation, that's why I didn't go for it.

Comment: Note that the `-assumenosideeffects` approach for Timber will not work when your app code is in Kotlin. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/74895567/56285