# How to strip logs with Timber.tag.(...).d(...) format using ProGuard?

Tags: android, android-studio, proguard, timber-android

I need to strip down all my Timber logs in my production build. I have added the following in my proguard-project.txt :

```
-assumenosideeffects class timber.log.Timber* {
        public static *** tag(...);
        public static *** v(...);
        public static *** i(...);
        public static *** w(...);
        public static *** d(...);
        public static *** e(...);

-assumenosideeffects class timber.log.Timber.tag* {*;}
}
```

However only logs with the format `Timber.e()` or `Timber.i()` etc is being stripped. Logs with `Timber.tag(..).i(...)` are not getting stripped.

Is there any way to achieve this? Thank you

Comment: obviously because you it is `Tree.i(...)` `Tree.d(...)` (it is obvious when you check what `Timber.tag(...)` returns)

Comment: @Selvin so what should i add in my proguard-project.txt file?

Comment: add `assumenosideeffects`  to `timber.log.Timber.Tree.v/d/i/etc.`

Answer (score 2):

wouldn't it be easier to do something line

```
if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
  Timber.plant(Timber.DebugTree())
}
```

in your Application subclass? This way you will the logs only in debug

Comment: i am aware of this solution exists, but the requirement is to have 2 flavors of release builds, one with logging enabled, and other with logs completely stripped .

Comment: BuildConfig has also the flavor info

Comment: Yea, my co-worker wants the comments to be stripped down completely, as the ```if (BuildConfig.xxx)``` can be bypassed if the apk is decompiled and edited. So , really need that proguard solution :/

Answer (score 1):

Stripping `Timber.tag(...)` cannot be done via Proguard. According to the [usage guide](https://www.guardsquare.com/manual/configuration/usage),

> In the optimization step, ProGuard can then remove calls to such methods, if it can determine that the return values aren't used.

Since `Timber.tag(...)` will return a `Timber.Tree` object, Proguard optimizer will not strip it off for you. Therefore, if you really want to strip off the log, you have to wrap it via a function e.g.

```kotlin
fun printDebugLog(tag: String, message: String) {
    Timber.tag(tag).d(message)
}
```

Then you can use `-assumenosideeffects` to strip off `printDebugLog` call. Another thing you have to be aware of that when your class is in Kotlin, the following rules cannot be used to strip off Timber logs also

```
-assumenosideeffects class timber.log.Timber* {
    public static *** d(...);
    public static *** v(...);
    public static *** i(...);
}
```

This is because when you decompile the Kotlin class to Java, logging will actually translated to

```kotlin
Timber.Forest.d(...)
```

Which will not be stripped off for the similar reason.

Comment: Is there actually _any_ way of stripping e.g. `Timber.d("..")` calls when app code is in Kotlin? Via some rules against `timber.log.Timber$Forest` for example?

Comment: Well, I guess the only way would be to introduce TimberWrapper or such and replace all direct Timber uses (that need to be stripped) with that. (Similar to `printDebugLog` in this answer.)